# Create view SQL with same columns in two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I have two tables with a common column and I need to create a view with all the attributes of the two tables, but when trying to do that

```
CREATE VIEW prova AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM sample s, statistics stat 
    WHERE s.sample_ID = stat.sample_ID
```

or

```
CREATE VIEW allData AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Sample s 
        INNER JOIN statistics stat vs ON s.sample_ID = stat.sample_ID)
```

gives error because the column sample_ID is repeated two times.
How can I create the view without specificing all the attributes one by one?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Second, it is usually a best practice to define all the columns for a view explicitly.  This can prevent problems down the road.

However, that is not your question.  If the only duplicated column is the `JOIN` key, you can use `USING`:

```
CREATE VIEW prova AS
    SELECT *
    FROM sample s JOIN
         statistics stat 
         USING (sample_ID);
```

If there are other duplicated columns, you will still have a problem.  One convenience is to take all columns from one table and  list the others:

```
CREATE VIEW prova AS
    SELECT s.*, stat.col1, stat.col2, . . .
    FROM sample s JOIN
         statistics stat 
         USING (sample_ID);
```